# Add screenshot to help page "What should I do when someone answers my question?"

Tags: feature-request

Some people can read, others need pictures. I find a lot of new members don't know how to accept an answer because they don't see or recognize the check mark.

Can the help page [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) please be edited to include a screenshot of what the asker will see next to an answer in their question and where they need to click? The words don't seem to cut it for some.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: The screenshot is kind of in the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), that could be re-used. One other point. I don't recall having seen any images in the help center. If there isn't a technical reason there probably is a philosophical reason...

Comment: The tour is a great link. I'll send people there, then. Who downvoted this and why?

Comment: Three downvotes and two upvotes. Can people please also add a comment if they downvote.

Comment: On meta the voting is a little bit more harsh, is still anonymous and on feature requests a down vote means: don't bother spending time on this.

Answer (score 2):

The [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) does the job nicely. No need to change the help page if images don't fit into the concept.